# How to send email with PowerShell (server smtp)

Tags: powershell, smtp

Hello I was assigned a task to create a script that performs several actions and in addition I need to send an email with a table that specifies the full name and folder path.
And the email sender will be NO@REPLY.COM
How can I do that? I use SMTP server

This is the script I created:

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=meitavdash,OU=Users,DC=meitav,DC=co,DC=il"

Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} |Format-Table name,SamAccountName,whenCreated

Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | Select-Object @{n='FullName';e={$_.Name}},@{n='UserName';e={$_.SamaccountName}},@{n='CreateDate';e={$_.WhenCreated}} |  export-csv -path c:\userexport.csv
Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | where {$_.whencreated -le (Get-Date).AddYears(-2)}|Select-Object @{n='FullName';e={$_.Name}} 

$sp=$((Get-Date).AddDays(-365*2)); Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {name -like "A*" -and whenCreated -ge $sp}|%{New-Item -Path "c:\temp" -ItemType Directory; icacls /T /grant "$($_.samaccountname):(OI)(CI)F"
```

Comment: Is your question how to use PowerShell to send an email? Look at the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet. To convert a table to HTML look at the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet. I don't see how the script that you created is related to sending an email. Edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: My task started by exporting a CSV file from AD with username filters, full name and creation date which I was able to do then I had to import the file back with filtering every user whose creation date over two years create a folder with his name and full permissions for it.
Now I need to send an email with a table that states the full name and folder path and that the sender will be NO@REPLY.COM

Comment: Wow.. 5 lines of code and in each of them you call `Get-ADUser`. Once would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the Send-MailMessage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7

```
$body = @"
Body
"@
$email = @{
  From = "Email address"
  To = "Email address"
  Subject = "Subject"
  Body = $body
  SmtpServer = "SmtpServer"
}
Send-MailMessage @email
```

Inside body instead of here string , you can use the full file name and paths as a pscustomobject.

Comment: My task started by exporting a CSV file from AD with username filters, full name and creation date which I was able to do then I had to import the file back with filtering every user whose creation date over two years create a folder with his name and full permissions for it. Now I need to send an email with a table that states the full name and folder path and that the sender will be NO@REPLY.COM